# Spring: Do I need to/should close InputStream when passed as Controller-method parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

A file upload is handled by using the following method in a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somePath/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void upload(@RequestHeader("content-disposition") final String contentDisposition, final InputStream binaries,
        final HttpServletResponse resp) {

// extracting file name from "Content-Disposition" header

// copying binaries to new file under a specified path
}
```

Now, I wonder, if I have to close the `InputStream` or if Spring does that on its own. And how does Spring react if an error occurs while the stream is processed?

Comment: The streams are handled by the Servlet container, not Spring MVC. If an error occurs, an exception will be thrown. If your code doesn't handle it, Spring MVC will use its registered exception handlers.

Comment: So, I don't have to close them within the controller method?